# How to sort the values (ArrayList<String>) in HashMap

Tags: collections

I am trying to sort this .

```
{Cars=["B","Z","A"],Vegetables=["P","J","H"]}
```

Here , Cars and Vegetables are keys and remaining are their respective values and we need to sort by values.

Answer should be

```
   {Cars=["A","B","Z"], Vegetables=["H","J","P"]}
```

I tried using the Comparator

```
     List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>(map.entrySet());
      Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>() {
     public int compare(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l1, Map.Entry<String,List<String>> l2) {
                    return l1.getValue().get(0).compareTo(l2.getValue().get(0));
            }
  });
```

This didn't work , it showed the wrong answer. Can you please help me. Am new to collections

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort only `list<String>` not whole map .

```
entries.stream().
forEach(stringListMap1 -> stringListMap1.values().stream().
forEach(strings -> strings.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2))));
```

Below its my working example;

```
List cars   = Arrays.asList("B","Z","A");
        List vegatable   = Arrays.asList("H","J","P");
        Map<String,List<String>> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();
        stringListMap.put("cars",cars);
        stringListMap.put("vegetables",vegatable);
        List<Map<String,List<String>>> entries = new ArrayList();
             entries.add(stringListMap);
                entries.stream().forEach(stringListMap1 -> 
stringListMap1.values().stream().forEach(strings -> strings.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2))));
        System.out.println(entries);
```

output

```
[{cars=[A, B, Z], vegetables=[H, J, P]}]
```